# How to add Array Object and Data to JSON in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

How to add Array Object and Data to JSON in Laravel

`$json = {'id':5, 'name':'Hassan'};`

I want to add new object `role` and value `Admin` to `$json`

I want result like

`$json = {'id':5, 'name':'Hassan', 'role':'Admin'};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$object = json_decode($json);
$object->role = 'Admin';
$json = json_encode($object)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could decode the JSON, add the values you want and then encode it back to JSON:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$data['role'] = 'Admin';

$json = json_encode($json);
```

[json_decode() Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
[json_encode() Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)