# how to add sub array to main array in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have created an array

> $json

```
$json = array(
 "att1" => '1',
 "att2" => '2',
 "details" => null
);
```

how to add sub array in main array [details] using for each,

so my final $json will be like

```
{
"att1" : "1",
"att2" : "2",
"detail":[
    {
        "a": "value"
        "b": "value"
    },
    {
        "a": "value"
        "b": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `details => $domeVariable`?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$json = array(
 'att1' => '1',
 'att2' => '2',
 'details' => null
);
```

Arrange your details array here.

```
$detailsArray =  [
    [
        "a" => 'value',
        "b" => 'value'
    ],
    [
        "a" => 'value',
        "b" => 'value'
    ]
];
```

Just put your data into your required array field

```
$json['details'] = $detailsArray;
```

You'll need to use PHP built-in function json_encode for converting it into JSON.

```
$json = json_encode($json); 

print_r($json);
```

The output is exactly what you need

```
{
"att1" : "1",
"att2" : "2",
"detail":[
    {
        "a": "value"
        "b": "value"
    },
    {
        "a": "value"
        "b": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($someArr as $arrElement) {
  $json['detail'][] = array('a' => $arrElement, 'b' => $arrElement);
}

$result = json_encode($json);
```

You question is not really clear. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

when you have a json , you must decode it to get your object:

```
$object = json_decode($json);
```

then: you can work with decoded object as normal object:

```
$object->details = $detailsArray;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55151110/10573560

short tutorial in:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_json_decode.asp